# Get to the core of [dual-core], [quad-core], and [multi-core]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I suggest merging [dual-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-core), [quad-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/quad-core) into [multi-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-core). I propose this because there is no reason to have multiple tags on one topic.

**Uses for [multi-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-core)**

- Virtualbox
- Some OS have problems with multi core
- Etc...

What is the final verdict? [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu) and [multicore](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multicore) or just [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu) and merge the others into it.

Comment: Yes, but quad core has twice as many cores as dual core.  And what about hex core.  I suppose you want to merge that in, too?  :-)  Good idea.

Comment: But I only have problems specifically with **TWO** cores! When I use fewer or more, everything works fine! I'm such a special snowflake! :( Why won't you let me be a special snowflake, fixer1234?

Comment: @allquixotic Lol, but that just adds another tag for people to choose from. If you can only use two cores, it is probably a software problem :)

Comment: I was kidding. :)

Comment: @allquixotic I know... I said lol

Comment: @allquixotic - So it is agreed?  We will add the [special-snowflake] tag?

Comment: I'd think even multicore is very meta.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - to what extent are multi-core questions processor-specific?

Comment: AU contrare, they are *non* specific, and I don't think there's too many issues *specific* to multicore systems

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Synonymizing or changing to CPU maybe?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek True, but Virtualbox and the likes...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I looked through the questions and many deal with issues specific to multi-core processors.  Is your point that it isn't necessary to differentiate single vs. multi because  simply using [cpu] will attract the right readers?

Comment: yup. precisely.

Comment: How about this title: Get to the core of [dual-core], [quad=core], and [multi-core]  ?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah...

Comment: So what's the final verdict, have [multi-core] plus [cpu] or just [cpu]?

Comment: I'm more on the 'just [cpu]' fence personally

Comment: @Robotnik Maybe, but nothing's official yet :(

Comment: I find having a tag that recognizes the multi-core aspect of CPUs useful vs. having only the [cpu] tag.  But I'd go for "one [multi-core] tag to rule them all"!